# CSS: hexagon with text on div with background-image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS code:

```css
.hex {
  width: 150px;
  height: 86px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: auto 173px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 25px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  zoom: 1;
}
.hex a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.hex .corner-1,
.hex .corner-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -2;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.hex .corner-1 {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hex .corner-2 {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hex .corner-1:before,
.hex .corner-2:before {
  width: 173px;
  height: 173px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: inherit;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.hex .corner-1:before {
  transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(-87px, 0px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.hex .corner-2:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-48px, -11px);
  bottom: 0;
}
/* Custom styles*/

.hex .inner {
  color: #eee;
}
.hex h4 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.hex hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.hex p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Kotta One', serif;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hex.hex-3 {
  background: #80b971;
}
```

```html
<div class="divWithBackgrounImage">
  <div class="hex hex-3">
    <div class="inner">
      <h4>CONTACT US</h4>
      <hr />
      <p>We Open Everyday</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <div class="corner-1"></div>
    <div class="corner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that z-index with negative values are hidden behind the background image. If I use positive z-index than I have no text in my hexagon. How to solve this problem?

Comment: replacing the complex hex hack with a single svg image would make everything easier and cleaner IMO

Comment: @Denys Séguret Thank you very much for great idea! But is it possible to make svg hexagon with text inside?

Comment: Of course you can. You can also set the text (or any part of a svg) with javascript. And you can also use the svg as a background for a div having the text.

Comment: @Denys Séguret Could you provide an example? I would accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more versatile solution than CSS shape hacks is to use SVG. For example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="300" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polygon class="hex" points="300,150 225,280 75,280 0,150 75,20 225,20" fill="#fa5" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(10)"></polygon>
    <text x="160" y="160" 
        font-family="Verdana" 
        font-size="30"
        text-anchor="middle"
    >
    Any Text Here
    </text>  
</svg>
```

There are many possibilities:

- have a static SVG, either served as an image or inline (as in this snippet)
- use the SVG as background of a div with text, or make the SVG contain the text (as in the snippet)
- use JavaScript to dynamically set the text (or other attributes, like colors or size) in the image
- fully generate the SVG with JavaScript (that's my usual practice, I even have a micro library for that: [hu.js](https://github.com/Canop/hu.js)), this solution is suited to a fully dynamic content, as is more and more frequent